# How to bind form with complex model data in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i am learning mvc.here i have one model. now i want to build form using html helper . so when index action will be called then i want to populate model data by hand and send the model to view. here is my model data but the way i want to build form not being possible just due to lack of knowledge. so if possible help me

```
namespace MvcPractise.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name Required")] // textboxes will show
        [Display(Name = "First Name :")]
        [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "First Name cannot be longer than 5 characters.")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name Required")] // textboxes will show
        [Display(Name = "Last Name :")]
        [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Last Name cannot be longer than 5 characters.")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "DOB require")] // datepicker will show
        [Display(Name = "DOB :")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Dob { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "State Required")] // drodown will show
        [Display(Name = "State :")]
        public List<State> State { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "City Required")] // drodown will show
        [Display(Name = "City :")]
        public List<City> City { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Language known Required")] // group of checkboxes will show
        [Display(Name = "Language known :")]
        public List<Language> Language { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Sex Required")] // group of radio button will show
        [Display(Name = "Sex :")]
        public List<Sex> Sex { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Computer Course Required")] // listbox will show
        [Display(Name = "Computer Course Done :")]
        public List<ComputerCourse> ComputerCourse { get; set; }

    }

    public class State
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class City
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Language
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Sex
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class ComputerCourse
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

1) for the first name & last name property i want to show textboxes

2) for the DOB property i want to show textbox with date picker

3) for the DOB property i want to show textbox with date picker

4) for the State/City property i want to show dropdown or combo

5) for the Language property i want to show group of checkboxes

6) for the Sex property i want to show 2 radio button for male & female

7) for the Computer Course property i want to show listbox

now write a index action method which will populate model with dummy data and generate UI. when click on save button then model data will return back to action method called saved like

public ActionResult Save(Student s)
{
   return View(s);
}

or

public ActionResult Save(StudentViewModel sv)
{
   return View();
}

guide me how to proceed. thanks

### UPDATE

can i manually populate our model this way

```
var model =  new Student()

{

    FirstName = "John",

    LastName = "Doe",

    Dob = DateTime.Now,

    State = new list<State>()
        {
            new state({ID="1" , Name = "test1"});
            new state({ID="2" , Name = "test2"});
            new state({ID="3" , Name = "test3"});
        };

}
```

specially see this code....does it work bcoz i am not before my pc now.

```
 State = new list<State>()
            {
                new state({ID="1" , Name = "test1"});
                new state({ID="2" , Name = "test2"});
                new state({ID="3" , Name = "test3"});
            };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) for the first name & last name property i want to show textboxes

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.FirstName)
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.LastName)
```

> 2) for the DOB property i want to show textbox with date picker

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Dob, new { @class = "datePicker" })
```

Now pick a favorite javascript date picker library and attach it to all elements that have the date class. For example you could use [`jQuery UI datepicker`](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/):

```
$(function() {
    $('.datePicker').datepicker();
});
```

> 4) for the State/City property i want to show dropdown or combo

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedState, new SelectList(Model.State, "ID", "Name"))
```

Notice the `SelectedState` property used here. You will need to add it to your model as a string property in order to hold the value.

> 5) for the Language property i want to show group of checkboxes

Start by adding a boolean property to your Language model in order to know whether it was checked or not:

```
public class Language
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Language.Count;i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Language[i].ID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Language[i].Name)
    @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.Language[i].Selected, Model.Language[i].Name)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model.Language[i].Selected)
}
```

> 6) for the Sex property i want to show 2 radio button for male & female

Then declare it as string, not some list:

```
public string Sex { get; set; }
```

and then in your view:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Sex, "Male")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Sex, "Female")
```

> 7) for the Computer Course property i want to show listbox

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedCourses, new SelectList(Model.ComputerCourse, "ID", "Type"))
```

> now write a index action method which will populate model with dummy data and generate UI

```
public AcitonResult Index()
{
    Student student = ... go hit your backend to get a student
    return View(student);
}
```

Inside the view you will have a form:

```
@model Student
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ... generate the desired input fields

    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

and then a POST action which will be invoked when the form is submitted:

```
[HttpPost]
public AcitonResult Index(Student student)
{
    ...
}
```

Also it is best practice to use a view model instead of passing to your view your domain models.

Comment: thanks u so much for the detail code. i am new so i would like to request one more thing that how to populate my model manually and send the model data with view from action method. when we click on save button then how that action method will look like. if possible so please help me with more code whenever you get some time. thanks

Comment: what will be the problem if i manually populate my model and send the mode to view instead of view model because u said to use viewmodel. looking for answer. thanks

Comment: if possible guide me how to populate my model manually from action method and send that model to view. thanks

Comment: here i update my question plzz have a look and help me giving answer. thanks

Comment: why did u use HiddenFor means hidden field when generating checkboxes.